# Right way to update the same row multiple times with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an `order` table and I want to a "buy again", the `order` table contains a column `productDetails`. Inside this column I have an array with `products`.

To do this "buy again" action, I need to put the same array inside my cart. In time to update important information (check if has stock, if the product are active on catalog, etc), for every product in array I'll do an update on my cart table, basically, I'll trying the following:

I'm using `node.js` and `sequelize.js` to do this:

```js
// Get the older order
const order = await Order.findOne({
    include: [
        {
            model: OrderProduct,
        },
    ],
    where: {
        orderId,
    },
});

// If the cart have something inside, clean the cartDetails column
await CartService.clean(order.userId);

// The addProduct do the checks and insert the product inside the cart
await Promise.all(
    order.OrderProducts.map(async data => {
        await CartService.addProduct(order.userId, data.productMarketId, data.quantity);
    })
);
```

Perhaps, the `addProduct` are inserting only one product. If we have more, the map executes correctly but are added only one product in list.

When I run on debug, first the code calls two times (when I have two products on my Order) on the `addProduct()` so, the select that get the cart data always come empty and only the last product is inserted correctly.

Expected behavior with 2 products:

```
1. clean cart
2. enter on iterator (map or something else) (product 0):

  2.1. Select cart details (which is empty on first time)
  2.2. Insert product on cart

3. next item on iterator (product 1)

  3.1. Select cart details (which have one element)
  3.2. Insert product on cart

3. end of iterator with 2 products registered on my database.
```

What's happening:

```
1. clean cart
2. enter on iterator (map or something else):
  2.1.a. get the empty cart
  2.1.b. get the empty cart again
  2.2.a. update the product 0 on empty cart selected in 2.1.a. (following the stack of (a)
  2.2.b. update the product 1 on empty cart selected in 2.1.b. (following the stack of (b)

3. Return the cart with only one product inside (the last product).
```

**EDIT:** I did a video about the behavior: [video here](https://www.loom.com/share/f00da2583b8347838a3091342650d912)

And there is the original addProduct function (which uses `async`) and parallelize on first `await` (I put `/* ... */` on some places to make the question smaller):

```
  async addProduct(userId, productMarketId, quantity) {
        const productMarketData = await productMarket.findByPk(productMarketId, { /* ... */ });

        const productKey = Buffer.from(PHPSerialize.serialize(`SP_${productMarketId}`)).toString('base64');

        /* ... */

        const cart = await Cart.findOne({ /* ... */ });

        if (!cart) {
            cart = await this.clean(userId);
        }

        /* ... */

        const newCart = await Cart.upsert({ /* ... */ }).then(result => {
            return result.cartUserId;
        });
        return newCart;
    }
```

This behavior is related with promises? Or async/await behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.map does not work with async functions so you should modify Promise.all call to something like this:

```
await Promise.all(
    order.OrderProducts.map(data => {
        return CartService.addProduct(order.userId, data.productMarketId, data.quantity);
    })
);
```

**OR**

*sequential version*

```
for (const orderProduct of order.OrderProducts) {
  await CartService.addProduct(order.userId, orderProduct.productMarketId, orderProduct.quantity)
}
```

Comment: _Array.map does not work with async functions_, Actually it does, but it doesn't guarantee if the promise is fulfilled or rejected, it will also fire all the call parallel like `promise.all()`, but won't make sure if all got resolved.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but didn't worked. The same behavior happens using without async/await.

Comment: Does CartService.addProduct support parallel calls for the same order?

Comment: I suppose you should insert products sequentially and using transaction so the next product addition knows about the previous one.

Comment: @Anatoly, the cart calls in the same time, inside this, I have two async calls, those calls are parallel, I need to execute sequentially. And, no, no parallel support to those changes.

Comment: I updated the answer. Is it what you wish to achieve?

Comment: @Anatoly. Didn’t worker the update. As I do two async calls inside the `addProduct`, I believe that has something related with this. I’ll update my question with the function structure.

Comment: @Anatoly, I put a video with the behavior. With for, the problem continue happening. I believe that have something related about the `addProduct` function

Comment: maybe move a cart clean outside addProduct? addProduct should have a single responsibility,